# c++ How do I get variables from a class and put it into another class, and put it into a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, variables, constructor, header

I have 2 h and cpp files. 
I wanna know how to call variables from the Abe.h file or the Abe class to the Bob.h or the Bob class. Please help.

Abe.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef ABE
#define ABE

class Abe
{
    private:
    int num;

    public:
        Abe();
        Abe(int);
        void showNumber();

};
#endif // ABE
```

Abe.cpp

```
#include "Abe.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Abe::Abe()
{
    num=45;
}

Abe::Abe(int n)
{
    num=n;
}

void Abe::showNumber()
{
    cout<<num;
}
```

BOB.h

```
#include "Abe.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#ifndef BOB
#define BOB

class Bob
{
private:
    Abe a;

public:
    Bob(Abe);
    void showNum();
};

#endif // BOB
```

BOB.cpp

```
#include "Abe.h"
#include "Bob.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Bob::Bob(Abe a1)
{
    a=a1;
  //^not sure what a=a1 is doing but if you could explain in simple terms or in deatil that would help.
}

void Bob::showNum()
{
    //how do I display it here??
}
```

so how do I get "num" from the Abe class and use it in the Bob class?
please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a=a1`assigns the `Abe` passed into `Bob`'s constructor to `Bob`'s `a` member. Probably a good idea to use more descriptive variable names and there are some optimizations to be gained by using the initializer list. Example:

```
Bob::Bob(Abe a1):a(a1)
{
}
```

Now that `Bob` has an `Abe`, it can... Do nothing to get the number from Abe. Abe has to allow  `Bob` to get the number. To do this redefine `Abe` in one of two ways:

```
class Abe
{
    private:
    int num;

    public:
        Abe();
        Abe(int);
        void showNumber();
        int getNumber()
        {
            return num;
        }
};
```

Now `Bob` can

```
int number = a.getNumber();
```

or (and this is second because it is the less preferred option because it tightly couples `Bob` and `Abe`.

```
class Abe
{
    friend class Bob;
    private:
    int num;

    public:
        Abe();
        Abe(int);
        void showNumber();
};
```

`Bob` now has total access to the internals of `Abe` and can really mess the poor guy up if he wants to. Which is not nice. Anyway, `Bob` can now

```
int number = a.num;
```

`Bob` can read `num`, change `num`, set it to hopelessly bad values and generally be a jerk to `Abe`. Good thing `Bob` is a friend. The other downside is `Bob` now needs to know how `Abe` works on the inside and if `Abe`'s code is changed, `Bob` will have to change as well.

Comment: Thank God I used Abe and Bob hahahahaha the funniest thing I read all day "Good ting Bob is a friend." ...Thank You very much

Comment: but hey wait, i need more help please.. imma put it in the question

Comment: and how do I call it to main?

Comment: @IbrahimMunaser What does "imma" mean? I do not believe that is an English word.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment in the `Bob` constructor is just like any other assignment, it *copies* the data from `a1` into `a` the same way like e.g. this code would:

```
int a1 = 6;

...

int a;
a = a1;
```

---

Once you have an initialized the `a` object in the `Bob` class, you can call the member functions of `a` like any other objects. However, you can't access private members.

*One* solution is to add a *getter* member function to the `Abe` class which returns the `num` member, something like

```
int Abe::getNumber() const
{
    return num;
};
```

Then you can use it in the `Bob` class like

```
std::cout << "the number is " << a.getNumber() << '\n';
```